# How can I get the distance between points in an array of coordinates starting from 0 in php?

Tags: php, foreach, coordinates, distance, radius

I trust you are well?

In PHP I have an array of coordinates. I want the distances between each coordinate starting from 0, so the first coordinate should be 0, then the second coordinate should be the distance between the first and the second and then the third should be the distance between second and the third, here is my code:

Coordinates:

```
$coordinates = [];
$coordinates[0]["Long"] = "299908186";
$coordinates[0]["Lat"] = "-271033949";
$coordinates[1]["Long"] = "281339992";
$coordinates[1]["Lat"] = "-261733281";
$coordinates[2]["Long"] = "280158333";
$coordinates[2]["Lat"] = "-262013500";
```

Here is the loop I want to do it in:
$earth_radius = 6371000;
$number = -1;

```
$long_from = 0;
$lat_from = 0;

$long_to = 0;
$lat_to = 0;

$angle = 0;
foreach($data as $row)
{
  $long_f_radius = deg2rad($long_from);
    $lat_f_radius = deg2rad($lat_from);
    
    $long_t_radius = deg2rad($long_to);
    $lat_t_radius = deg2rad($lat_to);
    
    $long_delta = $long_t_radius - $long_f_radius;
    $lat_deta = $lat_t_radius - $lat_f_radius;
    
    $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($lat_deta / 2), 2) +
    cos($lat_f_radius) * cos($lat_t_radius) * pow(sin($long_delta / 2), 2)));
}
  print_r($angle)
```

What am I doing wrong?